# How to download in python big media links of a web page behind a log in form?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm looking for some library or libraries in Python to:

a) log in a web site,
b) find all links to some media files (let us say having "download" in their URLs), and
c) download each file efficiently directly to the hard drive (without loading the whole media file into RAM).

Thanks

Comment: You can do it yourself with scrapy or pyspider. Also there is a company scrapinghub (creator of scrapy) that you can pay to do some scrapings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the broadly used [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) module (more than 35k stars on github), and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). The former handles session cookies, redirections, encodings, compression and more transparently. The later finds parts in the HTML code and has an easy-to-remember syntax, e.g. `[]` for properties of HTML tags.

It follows a complete example in Python 3.5.2 for a web site that you can scrap without a JavaScript engine (otherwise you can use [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)), and downloading sequentially some links with `download` in its URL.

```
import shutil
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

""" Requirements: beautifulsoup4, requests """

SCHEMA_DOMAIN = 'https://exmaple.com'
URL = SCHEMA_DOMAIN + '/house.php/' # this is the log-in URL
# here are the name property of the input fields in the log-in form.
KEYS = ['login[_csrf_token]',
        'login[login]',
        'login[password]']

client = requests.session()

request = client.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, features="html.parser")
data = {KEYS[0]: soup.find('input', dict(name=KEYS[0]))['value'],
        KEYS[1]: 'my_username',
        KEYS[2]: 'my_password'}
# The first argument here is the URL of the action property of the log-in form
request = client.post(SCHEMA_DOMAIN + '/house.php/user/login',
                      data=data,
                      headers=dict(Referer=URL))
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, features="html.parser")
generator = ((tag['href'], tag.string)
             for tag in soup.find_all('a')
             if 'download' in tag['href'])
for url, name in generator:
    with client.get(SCHEMA_DOMAIN + url, stream=True) as request:
        if request.status_code == 200:
            with open(name, 'wb') as output:
                request.raw.decode_content = True
                shutil.copyfileobj(request.raw, output)
        else:
            print('status code was {} for {}'.format(request.status_code,
                                                     name),
                  file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `mechanize` module to log into websites like so:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.example.com")
br.select_form(nr=0)  #Pass parameters to uniquely identify login form if needed
br['username'] = '...'
br['password'] = '...'
result = br.submit().read()
```

Use `bs4` to parse this response and find all the hyperlinks in the page like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

You can use `re` to further narrow down the links you need from all the links present in the response webpage, which are media links (.mp3, .mp4, .jpg, etc) in your case.

Finally, use `requests` module to *stream* the media files so that they don't take up too much memory like so:

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)  #URL here is the media URL
handle = open(target_path, "wb")
for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
        handle.write(chunk)
handle.close()
```

when the `stream` attribute of `get()` is set to True, the content does not immediately start downloading to RAM, instead the `response` behaves like an iterable, which you can iterate over in chunks of size `chunk_size` in the loop right after the `get()` statement. Before moving on to the next chunk, you can write the previous chunk to memory hence ensuring that the data isn't stored in RAM.

You will have to put this last chunk of code in a loop if you want to download media of every link in the `links` list.

You will probably have to end up making some changes to this code to make it work as I haven't tested it for your use case myself, but hopefully this gives a blueprint to work off of.